# Can I run a React Native app on a real iOS device from Windows?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a Windows machine and an iPhone and I was wondering if it's possible to run React Native on iOS easily like I can on Android. If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.
The only way is to install a virtual machine macos on windows like VMware or VirtualBox and run Xcode from it so you could run your app on IOS.